# How to Calculate the Limit of this function

Tags: limits

I need to evaluate
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^x}{x!}
$$
How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Rewrite the fraction by expanding the power and factorial as products.

Answer (score 1):

**REMARK**

You may want to think about what $x^x$ means for irrational $x$, it's not such a simple thing to define. I am assuming you really want it as a function of natural numbers $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**HINT**

If the limit exists and equals $L$, then the limit of $\ln f(n)$ converges to $\ln L$.

In other words, because $\ln n$ and $e^n$ are continuous functions, you have
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)
 &= \exp\left(\ln\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)\right)\right) \\
 &= \exp\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln\left(f(n)\right)\right)\\
 &= \exp\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)\right)\\
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Right, and you can finish with Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 0):

$x^x = x\times{x}\times{x}\times{x}...\times{x}$ ($x$ times)

$x! = x\times{(x-1)}...\times{1}$

Well, $x\ge{x}$, $x\ge{x-1}$, $x\ge{x-2}$,..., $x\ge{1}$

So, the limit is infinite.